# Ionic 3, Deep linking: must each @IonicPage component have its own .module.ts?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Considering the following Ionic3 project structure, I need deep linking to properly reflect the current "breadcrumb" in the url.

[image]

Main question: **must** I have a `src/pages/journal/add-entry/add-entry.module.ts` file? Or can `src/pages/journal/journal.module.ts` centralize all @IonicPages in subfolders as well as its own journal.ts component like the following piece of code attempts to?

**journal.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { JournalPage } from './journal';
import {AddEntry} from "./add-entry/add-entry";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    JournalPage,
    AddEntry
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(JournalPage),
    IonicPageModule.forChild(AddEntry),
  ],
  exports: [
    JournalPage,
    AddEntry
  ]
})
export class JournalModule {}
```

**journal.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-journal',
  templateUrl: 'journal.html',
})
export class JournalPage {}
```

**add-entry.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { IonicPage } from "ionic-angular";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: "page-add-entry",
  templateUrl: "add-entry.html"
})

export class AddEntry{}
```